# msiexec doesn't install msi

Tags: cmd, windows-installer

I want to install "foo.msi" from cmd command line. I run:

```
msiexec.exe /qn /i .\foo.msi
```

It returns almost instantaneously and foo.msi does not get installed. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

To root out the causes of error, I ran:

```
msiexec.exe /qn /i .\doesNotExist.msi
```

And got the thing. It returns immediately. No complaints about not being able to find the .msi or anything.

Does anyone know the proper way to use msiexec.exe to install an msi from windows cmd command line?

Comment: How is this a programming question?

Comment: We always use full paths in programming. Also `/le` logs errors to `/log file.log`. Also removing `/qn` may give hints -hiding output is never a good idea when you have a problem. Type `msiexec` for help.

Comment: If the installation fails an error code will be returned.  Use `echo %ERRORLEVEL%` to see this code.  0 means success; 3010 means that a reboot is needed.  If you want the GUI to tell you whether the call succeeded or failed, don't specify `/qn`.

Comment: Did you run the command line with elevated priviledges?

Comment: run: msiexec.exe /i foo.msi /qn /l*v install.log. Then see what's in the log file.

Answer (score 4):

msiexec runs asynchronously. If you want to wait for it to complete its work, use:

```
start /wait msiexec /qn /i .\foo.msi
```

Comment: Good point, I'd overlooked that.  (Probably because it only applies when running interactively from the command line, not from a batch file.)  Note that you still need to check the error code when you're done.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the first step to run your command with the logs option as below:

```
msiexec -i "foo.msi" /qn /L* "d:\logs\log.log"
```

Check the logs for errors. When I faced this, the issue was missing property values. That can be pass like below:

```
msiexec.exe /i "foo.msi" MYPROP1="myValue1" MYPROP3="myValue2"
```